# MVC : How to clear session and close the current browser tab on click of logout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to clear session and close the current browser tab on click of log out ?

I am trying to clear session on tab close but not able to find correct way.

Comment: you cannot reliably detect when a user closes a window/tab that's open to your site. you CAN intercept (with JS) when they click a logout button, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can send an ajax request to to an action method which clears the session variables and in the call back, you can close the window.

```
<a id=logoutLink">Logout</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

  $("#logoutLink").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post("@Url.Action("Logout","User")",function(res){
      if(res.status==="done")
      {
         //close the window now.
         window.close();
      }
   });
  });

});
</script>
```

Now in your UserController, Add the Logout action method

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Logout()
   {
      Session.Abandon();
      return Json(new { status="done"});
   }
}
```